# Snowflake- Calculate day of Quarter

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake has the simply function Quarter(timestamp()) which returns current quarter, but wondering how to do day of QTR , all tutorials reference Postgres/ sql server.

Goal - create a date table, and show what day of the quarter it is for the next 20 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT column1::timestamp as d,
    DATE_TRUNC('QUARTER',d) as q,
    DATEDIFF('day',q, d) as doq
FROM VALUES ('2019-10-30'),('2019-10-01');
```

gives 0 for the first day of the quarter, so if you need that to be 1 you can +1 that datadiff.

```
D                         Q                         DOQ
2019-10-30 00:00:00.000   2019-10-01 00:00:00.000   29
2019-10-01 00:00:00.000   2019-10-01 00:00:00.000   0
```

[Edit:] After re-reading your goal of a 20 year table, here is some code I have used in snowflake in the past to just that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE twenty_years_of_days(date) AS
    SELECT DATEADD(day, rn, CURRENT_DATE) as date,
          DATE_TRUNC('QUARTER',date) as quarter,
          DATEDIFF('day',quarter, date) as doq
    FROM (
        SELECT row_number() over(order by 1) as rn
        FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(rowCount => 365*20)) v
    );
```

Comment: I really not following from your description what you are wanting. If it's not a missed point of this question, I would ask another question, and show some examples of input and desired output.. which the lack of formatting in comments makes too hard.

Comment: no worries, I got it solved anwyay, but I checked off your answer as the soluiton. Thx again!